# How do i mount a usb device or a hard drive partition using python

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, ctypes, mount

I have been trying to write a program that would mount a device in a specified location, everything will be done by the user inputs.

I have used **ctypes**.
The place where I'm stuck is at this part

```
 def mount(source, target, fs, options=''):
  ret = ctypes.CDLL('libc.so.6', use_errno=True).mount(source, target, fs, 0, options)
  if ret < 0:
   errno = ctypes.get_errno()
   raise RuntimeError("Error mounting {} ({}) on {} : {}".
    format(source, fs, target, os.strerror(errno)))
```

I'm receiving an error saying *'Invalid argument'* and that is at

`mount(a, b, 'ntfs', ' -w')`

The following is my whole code:

```
import os
import ctypes

print "Usb device management"

def mount(source, target, fs, options=''):
ret = ctypes.CDLL('libc.so.6', use_errno=True).mount(source, target, fs, 0, options)
 if ret < 0:
errno = ctypes.get_errno()
raise RuntimeError("Error mounting {} ({}) on {} : {}".
    format(source, fs, target, os.strerror(errno)))

def umount(source):
 retu = ctypes.CDLL('libc.so.6', use_errno = True).umount(source)
  if retu < 0:
    errno1 = ctypes.get_errno1()
    raise RuntimeError("error unmounting {} ".
        format(source))


while True :
print "\n 1. Mount \n 2. Unmount \n 3. Write to file \n 4. Read File \n 5. Copy \n 6. Exit"
choice  = int(raw_input('Enter the choice : '))

if choice == 1:
    a = raw_input('Enter device name ')
    b = raw_input('Enter mount location ')
    mount(a, b, 'ntfs', ' -w')
    print "USB mounted"

elif choice == 2:
    print "Unmounting USB device"
    c=raw_input('Enter USB device location ')
    umount (c)
    print "USB device unmounted"
elif choice == 3:
    string = raw_input('Give input to write to file')
    fd = open("%s/file.txt"%(b), 'w')
    fd.write('string')
    print "file Write successfull"
    fd.close()
elif choice == 4:
    print "Reading file"
    fd = open("%s/file.txt"%(b),'r')
    print "File read successfull "
    fd.close()
elif choice == 5:
    copy_location = raw_input('Enter location to where it has to be copied')
    print "Copying file "
    os.system("cp %s/file.txt %s"%(b, copy_location))
    print "%s  %s"%(b, copy_location)
    print("File copied to location $s "%(copylocation))
if choice == 6:
    print "Exit bye"
    break;
```

And my system is Ubuntu 15.10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you look at `man 2 mount`, you'll see that the mount flags has to be a number, not a string. This is an obvious error; whether it's all the errors you have, I cannot say.

Comment: Sorry for the extremely late reply. But this does work.

Answer (score 0):

I would just use the command line mount.

```
import os
os.system("mount /dev/sd(x) /mountpoint")
```

Comment: I know and I have done that but I was learning about this I came across ctypes and now I want to learn this method too.